# How to automatically switch between the official 7" DPI display and a HDMI TV on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: hdmi, display, screen, output

I use a RPi3 with the Recalbox OS for some retrogaming. And I want to use the official 7" DPI monitor when it's portable, and the HDMI when I connect it to the TV.
I tried plugging the HDMI cable in, and it registers and switches channel, but the picture is just black on the tv and the 7" display is still working.

Can I somehow make this work automatically, without changing the config.txt file every time I want to change output?
Or is it possible to mirror the DPI output to the HDMI output?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, you need `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` in your `config.txt` if the HDMI screen is not connected at boot time. Otherwise, if you start without an HDMI screen but later connect it, it will not work until you reboot.